# Wait for handle/event async or call back within the same thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I have a global event created with CreateEvent, and I get a handle to this event in another application using OpenEvent.

Then I wish to do something like:

(pesudo code)

```
register_event_change_notification(my_call_back);

void my_call_back()
{
  // do work
}
```

Where my_call_back is executed on the same thread that called register_event_change_notification. However my problem is that I can't find any API's that allow this. It appears that you only have the following options:

1. Create a thread which uses WaitForSingleObject and then just calls my_call_back and put critical sections around everything.
2. Create a thread which uses WaitForSingleObject and block your main thread with a message loop, then post events when WaitForSingleObject to get my_call_back executed in the same thread as the message loop - which might not be the same thread that called register_event_change_notification.

This seems like a simple problem that must have been solved many times? Its overkill to have to deal with threading issues just to know when an event has been signaled IMO.

Edit:

In the end I went for using QueueUserApc - but it means your message put must use the *Ex API's to put the thread in an alertable state. Another gotcha is that you must track your outstanding APC's and not to destruct objects before they have serviced all of their APC's. Otherwise you'll get an APC queued to a destructed/deleted object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analysis of your options is correct. For option 2, which uses a message, you have two options to steer the notification to a desired thread. (a) For a non-GUI thread destination use PostThreadMessage. (b) For a GUI thread destination you can PostMessage or SendMessage to a destination HWND. The message is received by the thread that created the HWND.

Answer (score 0):

Here - http://pastebin.com/ucpDdYGZ - is my decision of a problem. Sorry for non-english comments (they are in russian).

The main idea is to create a dummy window with

```
m_wnd = CreateWindowA( "STATIC", "", 0,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

and to send it a message via `SendMessage`